# How to correct response XML before handleMessage is called + java web services

Tags: java, web-services

I always getting the Exception: MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in prolog. I guess the incoming xml contains invalid xmlchars, so I want to correct it before handleMEssage method is called. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SOAP Message Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler.html)

As Explained [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-client-side/) and [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-soap-message-handlers)